# char literal conversion on class constructor

Tags: c++

I have a class named `A` which defines a string literal conversion constructor `A::A(const char*)`. The constructor stores a copy of the string to a (private variable) buffer using `strcpy()`.

I know that a string literal is of type `const char[size]` where `size` the size of the string literal plus the `\0`.

I know that a character literal is of type `char`

In a main function I have a the following `statement`

`obj += ' ';` (obj type is `A`, `+=` operator is also defined)

And this is where it gets interesting.
If I am not mistaken the `char literal` should be converted to an object of type `A` and then the `+=` operator will do its job.
Unfortunately, the `conversion constructor` is never called and I end up with garbage values on the buffer.

Why is this happening ?

Edit:

```
#include<iostream>
//other headers
class A {
public:
    //some constructors here
    //operators 
    A(const char* foo) {
        std::cout << "string literal conversion" << std::endl;
    }
    A(char foo) {
        std::cout << "char constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    //irrelevant but...
    A& operator +=(const A& a) {
        std::cout << "hiiii" << std::endl;
    }
private:
    char buf[1024];
};
```

`obj += ' ';` wont print anything.

EDIT 2: solution
A preprocessor directive was inlining two variations of `+=`:

a) `A& operator+=(const A&);`

b) `A& operator+=(char c);`

Thus the strange behaviour.

Comment: Why do you expect that "char literal should be converted to an object of type A"? You only defined a constructor that takes a `const char *` as a parameter, and not a `char`.

Comment: It will be better if you will put here the whole code

Comment: @SamVarshavchik didnt work let me post the code

Comment: there you are code added

Comment: can you paste also your `+=` override method please?

Comment: @Clyky its irrelevant, the `the right hand of an expression will be evaluated first`. The interface of the `+=` is `A& operator+=(const A&)`. Thus, the `char literal` should first be converted to an object of type `A`

Comment: you might be right, but how is the code for `+=` "irrelevant" if you are asking why `obj += ' '` isnt working ??

Comment: you might also read about [mcve]

Comment: @KostasRim Did you step through the program to see which method gets called? The code you posted does not compile at the moment with a call to `+=`.

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek yes I have used print methods and nothing was printed, thats why I asked, I found it strange. Edit. I am compiling with `g++ -std=c++11 filename.cpp -o test`

Comment: http://ideone.com/fbVODP - can't reproduce. Please read [mcve].

Comment: Wait, `... -o test`? How exactly are you running this program?

Comment: @melpomene sec I will add the full code, terminal no debug flags

Comment: @melpomene you gave me the idea, I had a preprocessor directive which gave two variations of `operator +=` a) `A& operator+=(const& A)` b) `A& operator+=(char c)`. Thus the error... Really sorry for that, I will edit the thread. Can you please mark the question as closed ?

Comment: I have voted to close the thread, it was my bad. Thank you all for the help.